# MySQL date comparison function

Tags: mysql, date

In my table dates are stored in the format `"2010-08-26 09:00:00"` so yyyy-mm-dd. I'd like to select all fields that have a date field that is "today", so between `2010-08-26 00:00:01` and `2010-08-26 23:59:59`.

Just using larger and smaller than operators does not work, does MySQL have some built in date comparison functions that can do this?

EDIT: I should have mentioned dates are stored as `datetime` fields

Comment: What about records with a date of exactly midnight?

Comment: Fair enough, this is actually an in house planning tool and only office hour dates are entered (impossible to add before 8AM and after 8PM). My "between" values could reflect that but it makes no difference really.

Comment: Just a hint, there is also a BETWEEN comparision function in MySQL. It can be used like this: WHERE my_date BETWEEN '2010-08-26 10:00:00' AND '2010-08-26 12:00:00'. It does not apply in this case though as there are better functions for this. (BETWEEN works for any string, number and date)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
... WHERE DATE(field)=CURDATE()
```

or

```
... WHERE DATE(field)=CURRENT_DATE
```

or

```
... WHERE DATE(field)=CURRENT_DATE()
```

Pick one!

Comment: Just for completness: I usually use DATE(field)=DATE(NOW()) which might be less performant but easier to remember.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest `[...] WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),date_field) = 0 [...]`

Comment: Thanks for this information. I had been searching for this function (though not exactly the same problem) and your answer was helpful for me :)

Answer (score 1):

use function DATE()

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Answer (score 1):

Just a recommendation for the future: storing a date in a varchar column is almost always a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `DATE(`) function you should be able to construct a value for comparison:

```
DATE(2010-08-26 12:13:24)
```

will return just the date section for you ie. 2010-08-26.