# MySQL date comparison query

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have this table in my database:

```
table t

id   |  a   | b  | date_x

1    |  81  | 12 | 2018-03-16
2    |  9   | 54 | 2025-04-21
3    |  81  | 67 | 2018-03-16
4    |  763 | 81 | 2018-03-16
5    |  90  | 22 | 2025-12-08
```

date_x is type DATE

I would like to select the rows where a = 81 or b = 81 and date_x is before 2019-05-28 .

So I perform the following query in MySQL Workbench:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE a = '81' OR b = '81'
AND date_x > '2019-05-28';
```

This is what I get:

```
1    |  81  | 12 | 2018-03-16
3    |  81  | 67 | 2018-03-16
```

I would expect that 2018-03-16 is not later than 2019-05-28 . Moreover, why only 2 rows returned? There is another with same date in date_x column.

This query return the same:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE a = '81' OR b = '81'
AND date_x > str_to_date('2019-05-28', '%Y-$m-%d');
```

I have performed the following query for debug:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE a = '81' OR b = '81'
AND date_x < '2019-05-28';
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE a = '81' OR b = '81'
AND date_x < str_to_date('2019-05-28', '%Y-$m-%d');
```

then both return, as expected:

```
1    |  81  | 12 | 2018-03-16
3    |  81  | 67 | 2018-03-16
4    |  763 | 81 | 2018-03-16
```

I read the following Q/A but I'm still missing something:

- [MySQL date comparison function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574512/mysql-date-comparison-function)
- [MySQL date comparison issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229063/mysql-date-comparison-issue)
- [MySQL date/author comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918470/mysql-date-author-comparison)
- [MySQL Date comparison advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492729/mysql-date-comparison-advice)
- [MySQL date comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110862/mysql-date-comparison)

Any hint? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has the form

`SELECT * FROM t WHERE condition_a OR condition_b AND condition_c`

The `AND` operator binds more strongly than `OR`, therefore you end up with

`SELECT * FROM t WHERE condition_a OR (condition_b AND condition_c)`

This is where I think the confusion comes from. Nothing to do with dates as such.

Comment: It's at limit of obviuos. Thank you for help in focusing the right point

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your `select` in brackets. Because of it you get `WHERE a = '81' OR (b = '81' AND date_x >'2019-05-28')`.

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE (a = '81' OR b = '81')
AND date_x > '2019-05-28';
```

Comment: It's at limit of obviuos. Thank you for help in focusing the right point

Answer (score 1):

A rewite into

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE a = '81' AND date_x > '2019-05-28'
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE b = '81' AND date_x > '2019-05-28'
```

might make more sense especially when you consider performance, consider this table structure and indexing..

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `a` INTEGER,
  `b` INTEGER,
  `date_x` VARCHAR(10)
  , INDEX(a, date_x)
  , INDEX(b, date_x)
);
```

As

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE (a = '81' OR b = '81')
AND date_x > '2019-05-28';
```

can't use indexes see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n2hbEadSZAnXTsptV8wm8Z/0) and most likely ends up scanning the complete table/index files.

As the MySQL optimizer is costs based i also included [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n2hbEadSZAnXTsptV8wm8Z/1) to make sure the FULL scan for the first query was not simply triggerd by a to low number off records.. 
But it's but clear the second query has the more stabile plan..

Oracle database i believe does to `OR` to `UNION ALL` rewite direcly in this optimizer if indexed. As MySQL is owned by Oracle i hope they also add it that optimizion in MySQL.